# what are the different ways to invoke mvc action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have an action method in my controller.

We are currently invoking it from ajax jquery, and thats all good.
I was asked to invoke the action method using WebRequest or any other way.

I am trying the below and I am getting: 500 Internal exception - at GetResponse()

can somebody please advise is it really possible ??

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:52414/stealthApi/StealthData/");
    // If required by the server, set the credentials.
    request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    // Get the response.
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    // Display the status.
    Console.WriteLine(response.StatusDescription);
    // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
    Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
    // Read the content. 
    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
    // Display the content.
    Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
    // Cleanup the streams and the response.
    reader.Close();
    dataStream.Close();
    response.Close();
```

Comment: with an error 500, from ASP.net / MVC  you should also get a exception message,   what is this message.  Also you may need to provide the outline of the code for the action that is returning an exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Fiddler2 (http://fiddler2.com/) to compare 2 requests.

Possible reason:

- You're making GET request instead of POST

You cal also look in the EventViewer - it should write explanation of your 500 error

P.S. This is not the reason of your issue, but: use "using" statement instead of reader.Close()

Comment: sorry what is this for..it is throwing me out at the 3rd lone itself : request.GetResponse();

Comment: Yes, you receive error message at request.GetResponse(). That's because you have created wrong Request object. I recommend to install Fiddler2 and compare 2 requests: 1 from ajax, and the 2nd from your code.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this using HttpWebRequest and this is working fine